# Application structure if one object should be in many sub-domain apps

Tags: design-patterns, structure, project-management

I want to built game management. An user can play many games, each game has its own score, level, badges of user. So let me draw basic structure of this app:

```
Game-Management
    Game-1
       User: (internal logic of gameplay: how user move, how user buy item, how get user's score...)
    Game-2
       User: (other logic: how user add new user to friend list, how user get to battle, ...)
    ...
    Game-N
```

Back-end is very OK, because each game is developed by a team, these teams don't need to know each other.
But in front-end, I want to manage statistics of all user games. User goes to his profile page, this page list all game he played. When he clicks to a game, all statistics will be displayed. For example, he clicks to `Game-1`, he can view his score, all items he bought. If he clicks to `Game-2`, he can view his friend list, how many battles he joined.

But this is the critical point, because in back-end, my teams develop each game separately, and in front-end I want manage them in only one place. So this idea is good or bad? If it's good, how can I structure my application in both back-end and front-end? Otherwise, please give me other solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I would suggest you use Space Based Architecture.
It is widely used by gigantic companies like Google and Yahoo to build different types of modules that are easily integrate-able.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-based_architecture

So basically you have manager object, which will manipulate your model.
The functions on your model will only receive one type of message object for one model.
The functions on your model will also return one type of message object for one model.

So, you have `GameManager` object as Processing Grid layer. 
Then, you have `Game1Message` object as Message Grid layer. 
Next, you have the `DbModel: a.k.a User` object as Data Grid layer.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

This is a good point and i faced this issue a few times at the past.

I solved this in two different ways:

1. Store Stats / Logs Locally on the server and collect this from a central server.
   Pro:

   - Easy to control the load
   - There is no single point of failure
   - you gain some backup space on the local servers
   - each game can add more stats / data to the logs its easier to add this type of data
   - Local disk write is a very fast action, faster then RestApi. there is no net layer here.
   - You can control the work load on the central server

Cons:

- format should be met by all different servers
- Scaling up if one game is super popular can be a bit problematic
- You need to make sure the the files that write the logs are all synced
- Collecting with a central server can put high work load on one server
- at high volumes disks will always have a maximum capacity (~600 I/O SaaS , 5000 I/O SSD)

2.RestAPI on a central server that will handle all stats.e.g every game will report via API on Events that require Stats Tracking. You can also use a 3rd-Party Event recorder (Google Analytics events) and pull this report via API

Pros:

- Simple integration for the developers
- Easy to add new functions
- Scale up with the apps is easier. the API can direct to a load balancer that will direct to many
  server that handle the load

Cons:

- Network Load is now added to the server load
- Depend on network latency / Downtime
- Depend the game on another server load

The implementation is very simple with API , Local Logs can be a bit tricky. you need to distribute the logs format. create a known folder for the logs and create a map for the main server to know from where to collect the data and then parse this to a Data Base. although it sounds more complex i found the first method to be very effective and it helped me to reduce server cost.

Hope this help..